# How to calculate DATEDIFF in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have below code which is not working in ADF.

Are there any alternative functions to get difference between two dates.

Below is my code:

DATEDIFF("DD",START_DATE,END_DATE)<=10

Can someone please check and advise me how to proceed with this.

Comment: `Datediff` is a t-sql function. You can use this in query text box when SQL server/ Azure SQL database is used as a dataset. Could you share what is the source? Are you using mapping data flow for this transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Try using tick function which return the ticks property value for a specified timestamp. A tick is a 100-nanosecond interval.

```
div(div(sub(ticks(formatDateTime(parameters.START_DATE,'yyyy-MM-dd')),ticks(formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.END_DATE,'yyyy-MM-dd'))),36000000000),24)
```